# How to open a file in emacs from the terminal without a new instance of emacs opening?

Tags: macos, emacs, zsh, spacemacs

Does anyone know why my terminal opens a new instance of emacs whenever I run `emacs "filename"` from my terminal?

My google results about the issue showed too many occurrences of people trying to do this liberately, but my emacs is doing this by default for some reason.

I've found no resolving cases in my `init.el` or `~/.zshrc`

Comment: Why don't you open the file directly from within emacs, if it is running already?

Comment: I do that aswell but what I was looking for is the `emacsclient` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If emacs is already running, you can start a server (`M-x start-server`) from within emacs, and open files with `emacsclient` on the command line. You may create an alias for that.

Spacemacs has a `dotspacemacs-enable-server` setting in your init.el file (`SPC f e d`) to always enable the server.

Comment: That's right, I was looking for the `emacsclient` command. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty normal default behavior for any program. If you have a `cat` process running in one terminal, and you run `cat` again in another, they're not going to somehow share: you get two copies of `cat` running. The same thing applies to `emacs`. There are configuration options to change this, basically by making the first instance of `emacs` act as a server. Then the second `emacs` still starts a new process, but instead of continuing to set up a brand new editor it just sends information to the server process.